# setOnItemClickListener и setOnItemLongClickListener не работают в андроид 4.2.2

Tags: java, android, listview

Есть метод, вызывающий окно диалога:

```
private void showClipBoard() {
    mClipBoard = new Dialog(this);
    mClipBoard.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    mClipBoard.setContentView(R.layout.float_layout);
    mClipBoard.closeOptionsMenu();
    mClipBoard.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);

    // Закрыть окно
    final ImageButton closeButton = (ImageButton) mClipBoard.findViewById(R.id.btn_close_window);
    closeButton.setOnClickListener(new ImageButton.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                LatinIME.this.mClipBoard.dismiss();
            }
        });

    // Очистить базу
    ImageButton clearButton = (ImageButton) mClipBoard.findViewById(R.id.btn_clear_all);
    clearButton.setOnClickListener(new ImageButton.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dbHelper.deleteAllNoBlocked();
                displayListView();
            }
        });

    // Обновить базу
    ImageButton refreshButton = (ImageButton) mClipBoard.findViewById(R.id.btn_refresh_list);
    refreshButton.setOnClickListener(new ImageButton.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                displayListView();
            }
        });

    //Generate ListView from SQLite Database
    displayListView();
    showWindow(mClipBoard, true, true);
}
```

Здесь выводится список:

```
public void displayListView() {
    dbHelper = new CliperHelper(this);
    dbHelper.open();

    Cursor cursor = dbHelper.fetchAllClips();
    CliperAdapter mDataAdapter = new CliperAdapter(this, cursor, 0);
    listView = (ListView) mClipBoard.findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    listView.setSelector(R.drawable.cliper_one_row_bg);
    listView.setAdapter(mDataAdapter);

    listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> listView, View view, int position, long l) {
                showPopupMenu(position);
                return true;
            }
        });

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> listView, View view, int position, long id) {
                Cursor cursor = (Cursor) listView.getItemAtPosition(position);
                String currentClip = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("body"));
                enterShortcut(currentClip);
                LatinIME.this.mClipBoard.dismiss();
                dbHelper.close();
            }
        });
}
```

Это адаптер:

```
public class CliperAdapter extends CursorAdapter {
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;

    public CliperAdapter(Context context, Cursor c, int flags) {
        super(context, c, flags);
        mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {       
        if (cursor.getPosition() % 2 == 1) {
            view.setBackground(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.cliper_one_row_bg));
        } else {
            view.setBackground(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.cliper_two_row_bg));
        }

        TextView tvBody = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.clipBody);

        boolean value = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("fixed")) > 0;
        if (value) {
            tvBody.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.rowBlocked));
        } else {
            tvBody.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.textColorPrimaryDark));
        }

        tvBody.setText(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("body"));
    }

    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
        return mInflater.inflate(R.layout.cliper_row_list, parent, false);
    }
}
```

Суть проблемы: в андроид 4.4.2 и выше методы `setOnItemClickListener` и `setOnItemLongClickListener` обрабатываются, а вот в 4.2.2 нет.

При ответех прошу учитывать, что я начинающий программист, поэтому если возможно, то делать более развёрнутые ответы.

Comment: Почему бы вам не вешать слушатель нажатий  адаптере?.. Используемый вами способ имеет много нюансов и лучше его не пользовать.

Comment: Пробовал, но знаний не хватает, вот поэтому и прошу помощи.

Comment: Посмотрите мой ответ вот тут: [тык](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/499459/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8E-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%B2-listview-%D1%81-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC-%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BC/499506#499506)